# How to unshift new value with existing array with spread operator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to `unshift` an array value with existing array by using spread operator approach. getting error. any one help me to get correct approach?

here is my code :

```
uploadedFiles : [...state.uploadedFiles.unshift( (<fileActions.UploadFileSuccess>action).payload ) ]
```

getting an error as :

```
The Number is not array type
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two quick notes: 1. I'm going to guess from the name that `state` is a React state object. If so, you must never directly modify it (which `unshift` does). 2. `...` isn't an operator. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unshift` mutates the array and returns the new length of the array, which is a number, and that can't be spreaded. Your code boils down to:

```
 [...state.uploadFiles.length]
```

Now to do that in an immutable and correct way, don't use unshift, just add the element to the array before spreading the previous version:

```
 [action.payload, ....state.uploadFiles]
```

Comment: the try i made to add the new object as first member of array. as like your suggestion it puts the new member as last one...

Comment: @user2024080 - No, the above definitely makes `action.payload` the **first** entry in the resulting array.

Answer (score 3):

[`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) returns the new length of the array.

You need just to take the item without spreading.

```
uploadedFiles: [(<fileActions.UploadFileSuccess>action).payload, ...state.uploadedFiles]
```

If you like to update `state.uploadedFiles`, you could `unshift` in advance.

```
state.uploadedFiles.unshift((<fileActions.UploadFileSuccess>action).payload);

uploadedFiles: [...state.uploadedFiles]
```